# wp_insert_post() and multiple post from a query string in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to create a PHP file for my WordPress and use a form to create multiple posts by URL comma separated parameter's values.

When I submit my form, the URL is like:
 `https://example.com/import-number.php?numbers=1111,2222,3333,4444`

All values are comma separated, and I convert them in an array of values.

What is expected to end up being: 
`$titles = array(1111,2222,3333,4444);`

I'm using `foreach` loop to create a post for each number using `wp_insert_post` function. But it's just selecting first value while it should select all values and run `foreach` loop for every single values.

My `import-number.php` is:

```
<?php 
require_once "wp-config.php";

global $wpdb, $post;

$passurl = explode(",", $_GET["numbers"]);
$params  = array();

$i = 1;
    
foreach( $passurl as $params ) {
    if($i==1000){
        break;
    }
    
    $titles = array($passurl[$i]);
    $i++;
    
    wp_insert_post(
        array(
            'post_title' => $title,
            'post_category' => 16,
            'post_status' => 'publish'
        )
    );
}
?>
```

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not so clear. The post_title can't be an array.

Also in your code, the following is not needed:

- `global $wpdb, $post;`
- `$params = array();`

You should use the array key from the `foreach` loop instead of the variable `$i`.

The variable `$titles` is not used outside the loop, so why do you want it?

Maybe try instead the following:

```php
<?php 
require_once "wp-config.php";

$numbers = explode(",", $_GET["numbers"]);
$titles  = array(); // Initializing

foreach( $numbers as $key => $number ) {
    if( $key === 1000 ) {
        break;
    }
    $titles[] = $number; // add each number to the $titles array.
    
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( array(
        'post_title'    => $number,
        'post_category' => 16,
        'post_status'   => 'publish'
    ) );
}
?>
```

Comment: Well done sir. It's works fine. But in fact I just managed to use multiple post_title